# Fluent UI - Open Dropdown's callout programatically

Tags: fluent-ui

I have a use case where I would like to open the callout of the Dropdown programmatically.
I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find an option to do so.

I came across [one issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/13259) asking for the same but looks like at that time it was not a part of Fluent.

Not sure if I've missed anything. Is it possible?